# How to stop countdown after a few rounds?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var secondsP = document.getElementById('seconds');
var btn1 = document.getElementById("btnSurrender");
var clock = null;

btn1.addEventListener("click", surrender);

function timer () {

clearInterval(clock);

var start = new Date().getTime();

clock = setInterval(function() {




         var seconds = Math.round(15 - (new Date().getTime() - start) / 1000);


         if (seconds >= 0) {
           secondsP.textContent = seconds;
         } else {
           clearInterval(clock);
         }

         if (seconds === 0) {


         }
}, 1000);
}



function surrender(){

clearInterval(clock);
secondsP.textContent = 0;
setTimeout(timer,2000);
}


timer();
setInterval(timer, 17000);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
<script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
</head>
<body> 
<p id="seconds">15</p>
<button id= "btnSurrender">end now</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I need help with my little problem. I made a stopwatch which counts down 15 seconds. After this 15 seconds, it waits two seconds and starts again. You have option to stop counting when you want to, using "end now" button (then it'll start again after 2 sec). Now, my question is: how can I make a function which is going to stop whole counting after 3/4 rounds?

Comment: could you not just put the function in a loop and count the iterations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You restart the clock in `surrender()` using the call `setTimeout(timer, 2000)`. All you need to do is add an `if statement` inside that function testing a variable that controls how many times you have run the timer, and then call/not call `timer()` accordingly. Here is a working example of it: https://jsfiddle.net/L38q6k5d/, but just to give you an idea of how it would work:

At the top of the js file:

```
var timesRun = 0
var timerInterval = null;
```

Inside the `surrender` function:

```
timesRun += 1 // Increment it each time the timer ends
if (timesRun > 4) { // If the timer has run less than 4 times
    return; // this will stop the function here, so we dont start the timer again
}     
setTimeout(timer, 2000); // Reset the timer
```

Inside the `timer` function,

```
if (timesRun > 1) {
    clearInterval(timerInterval);
    return; // end the function here
}
```

When starting the initial timer:

```
timer();
timerInterval = setInterval(timer, 17000);
```

Complete JS:

```
var secondsP = document.getElementById('seconds');
var btn1 = document.getElementById("btnSurrender");
var clock = null;
var timerInterval = null;
// New Code
var numberOfTimesRun = 0; // this is where we keep track of how many times the timer has run

btn1.addEventListener("click", surrender);

function timer () {
    clearInterval(clock);

    // New Code
  if (numberOfTimesRun > 1) {
    clearInterval(timerInterval);
    return; // end the function here
  }
  // End New Code

  var start = new Date().getTime();

  clock = setInterval(function() {

    var seconds = Math.round(15 - (new Date().getTime() - start) / 1000);

    if (seconds >= 0) {
      secondsP.textContent = seconds;
    } else {
      clearInterval(clock);
        numberOfTimesRun += 1; // so we know that 1 iteration of the timer has been completed
    }

    if (seconds === 0) {
    }

    }, 1000);
}



function surrender(){
  clearInterval(clock);
  secondsP.textContent = 0;
  //New Code
    numberOfTimesRun += 1;
  if (numberOfTimesRun > 4) {
    return; // end the function there
  }
  setTimeout(timer, 2000)
  //End New Code
}


timer();
timerInterval = setInterval(timer, 17000);
```

Comment: Yes, but it works only when you stop counting using a button. And I wanted to stop it independently of what happened (button or time ends). My question was not clear enought, sorry.

Comment: changed my answer, also updated the jsfiddle for you